# button action with multiple parameter

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm working with swift. I've this view controller:

[image]

In this picture from 1.1.1 to 1.2.6 all are uibutton. This button r created programatically. Now on each button click I need to pass 2 parameter. If I consider **1.1.1 Overflater** , then I need to pass **"1.1.1"** and **"Overflater"** as parameter. I've tried like below:-

```
 ov_button.tag = "1.\(i).1"
 ov_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector("i3Vatrom.romBeskrivelse:")
, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

But it's not working. Any idea how to do this....

Comment: Your `#selector` syntax is wrong. Not relevant to your question, but it would be good to use `#selector` correctly.

Comment: @matt yes,  #selector(i3Vatrom.romBeskrivelse) this is right syntax. but I'm not getting how'll I pass parameter. any idea? and "tag" also not taking string value.

Comment: You're right about the tag. This is why I suggested a more elaborate solution.

Comment: @matt yes, I'm pretty new in iOS-swift. trying to understand subclassing and instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use `UITableView` hierarchy if you don't used `UITableView`, use `UITableView` and use `section` and `row` **tag** properties for managing your buttons. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function using for button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass anything to an action handler function. The action handler function automatically receives the sender (here, the button) as a parameter — and that's all. The trick, therefore, is to build the knowledge of the information you want passed *into the button object itself*, since this will be what is passed! In your case, it looks like you could just ask for the button's `title` for the Normal state and parse it into the `"1.1.1"` and `"Overflater"`.

Comment: there r almost 14 button there. May increase no of button according to DB. So need to create subclass for each button?

Comment: actually problem is, I'm not getting how'll I assign "1.1.1" to sectionNumber when button is clicking. So that I can use this in the function.

Comment: just 1 question. I've not created those button in tableview. Just adjusting X,Y coordinate, I've created those. So if I want to use cellForRowAtIndexPath then I need to create the button in table view. right?

Comment: Okay, I was assuming this was a table, because your screen shot looks like a table. If I were creating this interface, it would be a table. But it's just buttons, then just parse the button somehow in your action handler. For example, pull the info out of the button's `title`. (However, I think you should scrap your interface and use a table!)

Comment: ok. I'm trying to pass the parameter. otherwise will use table.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Check that. Whether it's an good solution or not. U're an experience swift developer that's why asking.

Answer (score -1):

after trying and thinking so much I found an easy solution of this question.

below code for button add target:-

```
ov_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(i3Vatrom.romBeskrivelse), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

I've used below function:-

```
func romBeskrivelse(sender:UIButton!) {

    let title = sender.titleLabel!.text!
    let titleArr = title.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
    print(titleArr) // print ["1.2.1", "Overflater"]

}
```

That's why I thought I must post the answer. may be this will help other.

Comment: Good, but isn't this exactly what I said? Ask for the button's title and parse it?

Comment: Actually I did not understand Your answer previously. Just now I read Your answer again and realised U've told the same what I did. So now thank U for Your answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Your code is also wrong. You should not be asking for the title label's title text. Ask for the _button's title_, as I told you in my answer.

Comment: I mean sender.titleButton!.text!

Comment: Ask for the button's title - not clear me. I'm getting button's title from this = sender.titleLabel!.text! . so what's wrong am I doing? correct me.

Comment: @matt I just use sender.currentTitle! and getting same output like previous. so is it the right thing?

Comment: Yes, that's more correct, but even better would be `sender(titleForState: .Normal)` as I suggested in my answer.